# Run SQL in several different databases with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm coding a project with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy, and in that project, I need to access unknown databases, and in those databases, execute queries with `db.engine.execute(<SQL>)`.

But how can I specify which database will receive the query?

Example:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:******@127.0.0.1:3306/api'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'db1':        'mysqldb://localhost/users',
    'db2':      'sqlite:////path/to/appmeta.db'
}
api = Api(app)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
@app.before_first_request
def create_database():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()


 @app.route('/test')
 def test():
    result = db.engine.execute("show tables;")
    names = []
    for row in result:
        names.append(row[0])
    return str(names)
```

How can I run `show tables;` In db1? And in db2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`get_engine()`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.get_engine) method in Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
engine_db1 = db.get_engine(app, 'db1')
engine_db2 = db.get_engine(app, 'db2')

sql = text("SHOW TABLES")
results_db1 = engine_db1.execute(sql)
results_db2 = engine_db2.execute(sql)
```